# Junk mail criteria used by Exchange and/or Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, dns, exchange, spam-prevention

Is there any documentation, official or unofficial, about how email ends up in the junk folder?
Emails from a domain that I am hosting ends up in my junk folder, and presumably in everybody else's junk folder. I would like to know if there is something I can do in DNS or elsewhere to correct the situation (I am actually not hosting the DNS record, just the website).

Comment: It'll probably learn from your decisions marking something as spam (Bayesian filtering) … would be interesting to know whether this happens on a fresh account as well or if you can reset the filter. Just to be sure: You never marked something as junk coming from that domain, right?

Comment: I don't mark anything as spam because the filter works pretty well otherwise, so there is no history it could be using.