# How to avoid exchange server to mark mails as junk mail

Tags: email, exchange, spam-prevention

I have a web-site that generates e-mail notifications to site users based on different events. For instance every week a status mail is send out. Another example could be that input from one user will cause mails to other users.

My problem is that the automatic generated mails often end up in "junk mail" for users using exchange server.

I can't figure out why.

The wording in the mails may be very similar (e.g. same text every week) and I been told that this will end up in "junk mail" as a bulk mail. What is a bulk mail and what is the definition?

In general I would like to know how I can avoid that my mail gets in the "junk mail" on exchange servers.

A description of the criteria used by exchange servers to determine "junk mail" will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Dupe (no answer in 3 years): [Junk mail criteria used by Exchange and/or Outlook](http://superuser.com/questions/473782/junk-mail-criteria-used-by-exchange-and-or-outlook?rq=1).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - Yes, I see the two questions touch on the same subject. Not exactly a 100% duplicate but very similar. Should I close this question or let it live for a few days to see if it can generate new attention?

Comment: I'd say leave it, and let the community decide. :)

Comment: What an exchange server does to filter junk mail can vary widely according to the admin's views on what constitutes junk mail.  I'm going to bet tho that the real problem lies in the web server with your domain also not having the correct SPF record.  Are you on a shared server?

Comment: @Tyson - I have a "rented/monthly pay" domain so I guess it is a shared server. I'm not sure what an SPF record is. Could you provide a link for information? For instance as an answer - then I'll check it out.

Comment: Info about [SPF records](http://bfy.tw/2c5t)

Comment: @Tyson lol - okay, I got it - stupid me...

Comment: To add... But it's nowhere near being an answer... The issue is most likely on the sending end, not the receiving end.  Two common issues are the SPF record for the domain being incorrect, and your web host sending your email from the same SMTP server that others use.  Shared hosts are very low cost and attract spammers, your mail coming from a spammy mail server can cause your sites email to get mis- classified.  Why is it not an answer?  Because I haven't even mention DKIM... More likely tho you issue is one of the two I mentioned.SPF or spammy origin server.